# Use key/value data from a file in a shell script

Tags: bash

I have a file called Year.txt

```
Year2000= 1/2/3/4/
Year2001= 5/6/7/8/
Year2002= 9/10/11/12/
....
....
....
Year2020= 100/101/102/
```

etc  and so on

I need to take this Year.txt as reference in my another script some sample.sh

**sample.sh**

```
source /home/user/Year.txt
d=cp $filename $1
echo $d
```

**sample.sh Year2000(passing Year2000 as first argument)**

**I need to cut the second part after = if I pass Year2000 as my argument and paste this 1/2/3/4/  in my statement

**I need to cut the second part after = if I pass Year2001 as my argument and paste this 5/6/7/8/ in my copy statement 
etc..

I need output like this:

**Input1** **sample.sh Year2000**

***Output***: cp somefile.txt 1/2/3/4/

**Input2: sample.sh Year2001**

***Output***: cp somefile.txt 5/6/7/8/

In Short -- I need to take the reference from another file and generate the copy statement

Comment: Does your input file really have spaces after the `=`? If so, it's not a legal bash assignment, so you can't `source` it.

Comment: Which shell are you targeting? Does it **really** need to be `/bin/sh`, or can you use bash? (Associative arrays are a very good fit for the problem at hand). Since `source` isn't a legal POSIX sh statement, it sounds likely you're already testing on bash anyhow.

Comment: We can change the input file with any delimiter, | , double quotes anything . but I need copy statement should be ready . It is not mandate to use =

Comment: echo $0 -bash . Doesn't matter .

Comment: It *does* matter. Bash disables features if you run it under the name `sh`; it **must** be invoked as `bash` for the full extended language to be available.

Comment: (Also, what your `$0` is at an interactive prompt doesn't really tell us much that's useful about which interpreter is used to run your scripts; you can have `/bin/bash` as your interactive interpreter but have `/bin/sh` used to run scripts -- indeed, that's very common).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `source` files that aren't legal bash code. In this case, an associative array lets you store as many key/value pairs as you need inside a single variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Needs bash 4.0 or newer" >&2; exit 1;; esac

year_name=$1
file_name=$2

[[ $file_name ]] || { echo "Usage: $0 year-name file-name" >&2; exit 1; }

# Read year.txt, and generate a map
declare -A dirs_by_year=( )
while IFS='= ' read -r k v; do
  dirs_by_year[$k]=$v
done <Year.txt

if ! [[ ${dirs_by_year[$year_name]} ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: User specified year $1, but input file does not have a directory for it" >&2
  echo "       ...defined years follow:" >&2
  declare -p dirs_by_year >&2  # print array definition to show what we read
  exit 1
fi

# generate and write a cp command
printf '%q ' cp "$file_name" "${dirs_by_year[$year_name]}"
```